# UTF8 Reacting differently on Turkey Region than US Region - C#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, internationalization

I wrote an API (C# .net standard) recently that connects to a TCP Server written by someone else. It uses custom packets centered around the HTTP protocol. When reading/writing packets I am using the UTF8 encoding. All of the clients who have used the API can connect correctly regardless of their Region. However, a user from Turkey (region set to Turkey) cannot use the API. When they change their region to United States, the API works correctly.

I was under the impression that UTF8 is supposed to be a universal standard and would react the same across any region. Is this not the case?

Tests:

- Windows 10 .net framework 4.6.1 - US - Success
- Windows 10 .net framework 4.6.1 - TR - Failed
- Windows 10 .net core 2.0 - US - Success
- Windows 10 .net core 2.0 - TR - Failed

Edit:

The reason why encoding is important is because there is a form of serialization done within the API. It serializes a Dictionary of strings into a single string using special characters that are defined at the beginning of the data stream. These special characters change depending on the contents of the stream.

Comment: What conditions define success/failure?

Comment: I have modified the question slightly with more information to answer your question. Success means it can deserialize the dictionary correctly.

Comment: Please post what code specifically fails, we cannot magically guess what's wrong nor why without seeing the actual code being executed. Also, if it fails both on .NET Framework and .NET Core, why point both of them out? Makes it seem like you were seeing different behaviors when that's not the case

Comment: The question is not aimed at a specific line of code, because there are multiple points of failure due to the steam not being Decoded correctly. The question is more framed around UTF8 not reacting the same on different regions. I can add the code, but there is a lot of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from this information the nature of the API call, but case sensitivity rules vary between Turkish and other languages, and that's the most common root cause for Turkish-specific errors.

In Turkish, the dotted lowercase i capitalizes to a dotted uppercase İ. A dotless lowercase ı becomes the English I when capitalized.

String comparison operations therefore need to use different rules depending on the use case. You probably want to standardize on EN-US or C Locale-style collation for command interfaces (In DotNet this is something like StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase). For applications like text search, obviously what is "correct" will be a more complex decision, based on your users' needs.

It's possible that you have issues either on the client side, on the server side, or a combination of both.

If you can clarify a bit more about the API call that fails and the mechanics of that call on the client and server side, I may be able to update this answer with more specific information applicable to your case.

Edited to add:
Based on what you've added, you may need to construct your dictionary object with something like `new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`.